# JApplet won't initialize if I call for graphics from another object

Tags: java, graphics, japplet, conways-game-of-life

I'm attempting to simulate conway's game of life in a JApplet. I have a main class, called Gameboard, which extends JApplet and implements MouseListener. I also have another class, Grid, which creates the grid image by drawing using the methods found in the Graphics class (drawLine, drawRect, etc.)

For all intents and purposes, class GameBoard does the following:
 - On init: Creates variables, attempts to create Grid object.

- Registers and records mouse clicks
- In paint method, calls for the Grid object's grid image.

Class grid does the following;

- On construction:

  - Creates an object of class Image, and then gets the graphics from that class for drawing.
  - Creates a grid using a loop and drawLine

However, my problem starts when I try to create a new grid object in class Gameboard. The gameboard will say in the applet window "JApplet not initialized" although I have 
an init class in gameboard that fires fine, as long as I don't create a Grid object. Why would this be the case? I did some experimenting, and found that if I don't call for Grid's Graphics there is no hangup - but also, no image, which is very important. Why would this cause an init problem?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: As an aside:  Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).